# NoSQL Database for ECommerce

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, e-commerce, orientdb, nosql

I will be constructing an ecommerce site, and would like to use a no-sql database, which will fit well with the plans for the app. But when it comes to which database would fit the job, im not sure. After comparing various DB's, the ones that seem best might be either mongo, couch, or even orientdb. I have seen arguments for all of them to be used or not used compared to something like MySQL. But between themselves (nosql databases), which one would fit well with an ecommerce solution?

Note, for the use case, i wont be having thousands of transactions a second. Or similarly high write rates. they will be moderate sure, but at a level that any established database could handle.

CouchDB: Has master to master replication, which I could really use. If not, I will still have to implement the same functionality in code anyways. I need to be able to have a users database, sync with the mothership. (users will have their own, potentially localhost database, that could sync with the main domains server). Couch is also fast, once your queries have been stored in the db.As i will probably have a higher need for read performance. Though not by a lot.

MongoDB: queries are very easy and user friendly. Also, with the fact that end users may need to query for certain things at a given time that I may not be able to account for ahead of time, this seems like it may be a better fit. I dont have to pre-store my queries in the db. Does support atomic transactions, though only when writing to a single document at a time.

OrientDB: A graph database. much different that most people are used to, but with the needs, it could fit very well too. Orient has the benefits of being schemaless, as well as  having support for ACID transactions. There is a lot of customer, and product relationships that a graph database could be great with. Orient also support master to master replication, similar to couchdb.

Dont get me wrong, I can see how to build this traditionally with something like MySQL, but the ease and simplicity of a nosql solution, is very attractive. Although, in my case, needing a schemaless solution, would be much easier in nosql rather than mysql. a given product may have more or less items, than another. and avoiding recreating a table whenever a new field is added, is preferrable.

So between these 3 (or even others you think may be better), what features in each could potentially work for, or against me in regards to an ecommerce based site, when dealing with customer transactions?

Edit: The reason I am not using an existing solution, is because with the integrated features I need, there are no solutions available out there. We are also aiming to use this as a full product for our company. There will be a handful of other integrations than just sales. It is also going to be working with a store's POS system.

Comment: Go look at SQL+Solr/ElasticSearch. SQL for moderate query/write rate, data safety and transaction safety (who wants two DB nodes to sell the same thing to two different people?). And Solr/ ElasticSearch for flexible (or no) schema, very capable ad-hoc queries and really fast to search. You can possibly back up your SQL DB to a single file each night.

Comment: @aitchnyu I am not sure that you justify the use of SQL that well. What do you mean by "two DB nodes to sell the same thing to two different people"?

Comment: There is an open-source e-commerce platform that uses MongoDB. Check it out: getfwd.com

Comment: I am curious as to why this was down voted. This seems like a very viable question to me, that I have seen others ask on the internet as well. And there doesnt seem to be a whole lot of info on how to pick a nosql database for an ecommerce site. @Darhazer I am checking out getfwd now.

Comment: I am also not sure what you mean by "two DB nodes to sell the same thing to two different people". using a nosql solution, i wouldnt need something like solr and elastic search, because all of my product data would be in one record. so its much easier to query for. Which reduces the complexity of having to use complex things like solr. I have not used it before but have looked into it. It may be simple to setup, but its another tool to add, when I wouldnt need  to. If I was to go with sql, sure. I will still research elastic search for flexible schema, though, to cover all bases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since *e-commerce* can encompass everything from shopping carts through to membership and recurring subscriptions, it is hard to guess exactly what requirements and complexity you are envisioning.

When constructing an e-commerce site, one of the early considerations should be investigating whether there is already an established e-commerce product or toolkit that could meet your requirements.  There are many subtleties to processes like ordering, invoicing, payments, products, and customer relationships even when your use case appears to be straightforward.  It may also be possible to separate your application into the catalog management aspects (possibly more custom) versus the billing (potentially third party, perhaps even via a hosted billing/payment API).

Another consideration should be who you are developing the e-commerce site for: is this to scratch your own itch, or for a client?  Time, budget, and features for a custom build can be difficult to estimate and schedule .. and a niche choice of technology may make it difficult to find/hire additional development expertise.

A third consideration is what your language(s) of choice are for developing your application.  Some languages will have more complete/mature/documented drivers and/or framework abstractions for the different databases.

That said, writing an e-commerce system appears to be a rite of passage for many developers ;-).

Edit: a lot has changed since this answer was originally posted in 2012 and you should definitely refer to current product information. For example, MongoDB has had support for [Decimal128 values](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/bson-data-types-decimal128/) since MongoDB 3.4 (2016) and  [multi-document transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions) since MongoDB 3.6 (2017).

Comment: There will be memberships, but it will be simple and not the main focus of the product. The main service this will be used as, is an in store POS, and a product catalog. Yes there are solutions out there, but many of the mare bulky and cumbersome. They also dont have options for the other features we need. Not to mention, we are trying to create this based on a startup, as a product/service to sell, along with using it as our own system in our store. Also, yea, each component of the application will be separated out into multiple plugins. Allowing for portability.

Comment: This will be its own product and service that we plan to have available for anyone to consume.It will also be used for a real storefront, and related business until then, that a friend own.The product is an idea from both of us to create as a startup.So far, the system will be written in python,as a desktop client will also eventually need to be done (in store POS).The master:master replication is simply a feature I would like to have for stores to sync their data online, if ever their local system fails.They should also be able to use the system from online, when not in store in other places.

Comment: "Master-Master replication (MVCC)" -- wut?

Comment: @capr Good catch! I believe past me was trying to associate MVCC as a requirement for multi-master replication since MongoDB's original MMAP storage engine was definitely not MVCC. However, my mention was very out of context in the original answer :blush:. A lot has changed in the past 9+ years across all of the mentioned products so I removed some outdated references. WiredTiger, MongoDB's default storage engine since 3.2 (2015), uses MVCC but multi-master replication would be a feature implemented at the replication layer (above storage).

Answer (score 2):

Check the comparison of different available NoSql databases [here](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis). Suit your requirement as per that.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 4 now multi-document ACID transactions! That makes it suitable for e-Commerce!

Check out: https://www.mongodb.com/transactions